# watchOS2 Notification Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchos-2

I encountered a strange bug from simulator of watchOS2 on XCode.

I handled a notification using UILocalNotification and modified storyboard of static notification. 

But when I check a value "Wants Sash Blur" and build, It makes an error related with "Carousel.app"(like an unexpectedly stopped.)

However, When I turn off that option, it works properly.

I don't know why it makes my app break down.

### Here is an error log

```
Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        19  com.apple.PepperUICore.Blur

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000028
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x28:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000087000-0000000000312000 [ 2604K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/Carousel.app/Carousel

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 201.3 - Device: Apple Watch - 42mm - Runtime: watchOS 2.1 (13S660) - DeviceType: Apple Watch - 42mm

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07602886 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x072987f8 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 298
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x072986c5 dispatch_semaphore_wait + 37
3   com.apple.PepperUICore          0x042b20b6 _PUICBlurApply + 456
4   com.apple.PepperUICore          0x042b2723 PUICBlurApply + 24
5   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x039a7fab -[CUISAlertPlatterView updateBlurWithContext:] + 885
6   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x039a7c26 -[CUISAlertPlatterView updateBlurIfNeeded] + 129
7   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x039a7a19 -[CUISAlertPlatterView didMoveToWindow] + 68
8   com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf6fae -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 2053
9   com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf6b83 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
10  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf6b83 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
11  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf6b83 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
12  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04c0dc3a -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 85
13  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf6b83 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
14  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bea9bc __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 180
15  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bea894 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 489
16  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04bf9f64 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2307
17  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04be8893 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
18  com.apple.Carousel              0x000f545e 0x87000 + 451678
19  com.apple.Carousel              0x0017b963 0x87000 + 1001827
20  com.apple.Carousel              0x00222373 0x87000 + 1684339
21  com.apple.Carousel              0x001b9254 0x87000 + 1253972
22  com.apple.Carousel              0x001e405f 0x87000 + 1429599
23  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e19a0 __22-[BSTransaction begin]_block_invoke + 115
24  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e63a3 -[BSTransaction _preventTransactionCompletionForReason:ignoringAuditHistory:andExecuteBlock:] + 64
25  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e18c7 -[BSTransaction begin] + 873
26  com.apple.Carousel              0x000f4616 0x87000 + 448022
27  com.apple.Carousel              0x000f3b1e 0x87000 + 445214
28  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023f2df1 -[BSEventQueueEvent _execute] + 43
29  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023f2dc1 -[BSEventQueueEvent executeFromEventQueue] + 33
30  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023eac29 -[BSEventQueue _processNextEvent] + 354
31  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023ea0d2 -[BSEventQueue _executeOrPendEvents:position:] + 954
32  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023ea183 -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvents:atPosition:] + 48
33  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023ea14b -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvent:atPosition:] + 92
34  com.apple.Carousel              0x000f3174 0x87000 + 442740
35  com.apple.Carousel              0x000d59f0 0x87000 + 322032
36  com.apple.Carousel              0x000d58ee 0x87000 + 321774
37  com.apple.Carousel              0x001c4908 0x87000 + 1300744
38  com.apple.Carousel              0x001c4656 0x87000 + 1300054
39  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e19a0 __22-[BSTransaction begin]_block_invoke + 115
40  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e63a3 -[BSTransaction _preventTransactionCompletionForReason:ignoringAuditHistory:andExecuteBlock:] + 64
41  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e18c7 -[BSTransaction begin] + 873
42  com.apple.Carousel              0x001f559d 0x87000 + 1500573
43  com.apple.Carousel              0x001f7fdd 0x87000 + 1511389
44  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023f2df1 -[BSEventQueueEvent _execute] + 43
45  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023f2dc1 -[BSEventQueueEvent executeFromEventQueue] + 33
46  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023eac29 -[BSEventQueue _processNextEvent] + 354
47  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023eae01 -[BSEventQueue _removeEventQueueLock:] + 145
48  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023e72e2 -[BSEventQueueLock relinquish] + 62
49  com.apple.Carousel              0x001f55c8 0x87000 + 1500616
50  com.apple.Carousel              0x001fe671 0x87000 + 1537649
51  libdispatch.dylib               0x0728f72b _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
52  libdispatch.dylib               0x072ad40d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
53  libdispatch.dylib               0x07295fce _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 689
54  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0662db3e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
55  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eb864 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
56  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eac76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
57  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eaa8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
58  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x04af2097 GSEventRunModal + 192
59  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x04af1ed4 GSEventRun + 104
60  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b39e96 UIApplicationMain + 160
61  com.apple.Carousel              0x00141872 0x87000 + 764018
62  libdyld.dylib                   0x072d1ae1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0760a7f6 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0729c2db _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 257
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0729c02b _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0760284a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07601c34 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065ec146 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eb526 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eac76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eaa8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x046a7601 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x0474d9cd -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
8   com.apple.UIKit                 0x051ca202 -[UIStatusBarServerThread main] + 967
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x04759e84 __NSThread__start__ + 1346
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cfa26 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf99c _pthread_start + 155
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:: com.apple.springboard.backgroundappservices
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0760284a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07601c34 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065ec146 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eb526 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eac76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eaa8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Carousel              0x00129cd0 0x87000 + 666832
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cfa26 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf99c _pthread_start + 155
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:: com.apple.springboard.icongeneration
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0760284a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07601c34 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065ec146 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eb526 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eac76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x065eaa8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Carousel              0x00129dc6 0x87000 + 667078
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cfa26 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf99c _pthread_start + 155
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 6:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.opengl.cvmDoWork
0   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09bec177 llvm::LiveIntervalUnion::extract(llvm::LiveInterval&, llvm::LiveRange const&) + 343
1   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09bf2f7f llvm::LiveRegMatrix::unassign(llvm::LiveInterval&) + 255
2   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c90c04 (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::evictInterference(llvm::LiveInterval&, unsigned int, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned int>&) + 532
3   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c902f8 (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::tryEvict(llvm::LiveInterval&, llvm::AllocationOrder&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned int>&, unsigned int) + 840
4   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c8ceed (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::selectOrSplitImpl(llvm::LiveInterval&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned int>&, llvm::SmallSet<unsigned int, 16u, std::__1::less<unsigned int> >&, unsigned int) + 557
5   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c8bcb9 (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::selectOrSplit(llvm::LiveInterval&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned int>&) + 121
6   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c8bf72 non-virtual thunk to (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::selectOrSplit(llvm::LiveInterval&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<unsigned int>&) + 34
7   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c83ba3 llvm::RegAllocBase::allocatePhysRegs() + 195
8   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c8badb (anonymous namespace)::RAGreedy::runOnMachineFunction(llvm::MachineFunction&) + 1499
9   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09c2311a llvm::MachineFunctionPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 106
10  libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x0a1b3e93 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 595
11  libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x0a1b380a llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Function&) + 186
12  libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x0a1b3710 llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager::run(llvm::Function&) + 96
13  libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09862c94 llvm::JIT::getPointerToFunction(llvm::Function*) + 180
14  libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18dd4b1e cvmContentBuildLLVMFunctions(_cvms_plugin_element_s const*, llvm::Function**, unsigned int) + 94
15  libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18dd48ff cvmsPluginElementBuild + 1039
16  libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x0973b110 cvmsCompBuildElement + 121
17  libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x0973ff5f cvmsServerElementBuild + 1002
18  libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x0973ba37 cvms_element_build_from_source + 107
19  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib      0x09734872 cvm_deferred_build_modular(void*) + 393
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x072ad40d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x07295076 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1065
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x072949c1 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 563
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x072981f2 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke_owning + 32
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x072ad40d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x07296598 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 744
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x072962a9 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf43e _pthread_wqthread + 1050
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0760289e semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x072987a2 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 212
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x072986c5 dispatch_semaphore_wait + 37
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x07297c91 _dispatch_worker_thread + 169
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cfa26 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf99c _pthread_start + 155
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x07609d76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 19 Crashed:: com.apple.PepperUICore.Blur
0   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x040b741f -[CARenderer dealloc] + 117
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060fe060 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060fd361 objc_release + 65
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060fd318 objc_storeStrong + 39
4   com.apple.PepperUICore          0x04223431 -[PUICLayerRenderer .cxx_destruct] + 65
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060e98dd object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 116
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060e9864 object_cxxDestruct + 20
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060f3cfc objc_destructInstance + 48
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060f3d2d object_dispose + 20
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060fe060 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x060fd361 objc_release + 65
11  com.apple.PepperUICore          0x042b3f21 ___PUICBlurApply_block_invoke + 3896
12  com.apple.PepperUICore          0x042b21b2 +[PUICBlurViewFactory performCABlurWorkOnBackgroundThread:] + 15
13  com.apple.Foundation            0x046a57f9 -[NSThread main] + 76
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x04759e84 __NSThread__start__ + 1346
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cfa26 _pthread_body + 138
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075cf99c _pthread_start + 155
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x075ccf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 19 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x7c326800  ecx: 0x00000002  edx: 0x147ac858
  edi: 0x040b73b8  esi: 0x7c39ee00  ebp: 0xb0830b48  esp: 0xb0830b20
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010206  eip: 0x040b741f   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000023   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000028

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: You should show the error, along with a backtrace.  Please set a user exception breakpoint, if you have not done this already, to aid in debugging.

Comment: @PetahChristian It is not a Xcode error so I CAN'T set exception point. If possible, I solve it myself.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.  Please post the report as text, so it is searchable. Can you create a sample project with minimal code to reproduce this error?  Then you can report the issue to Apple, that they may fix their SDK bug, as well as provide others an opportunity to examine the extension to see if anything in the bundle is causing this crash to happen.

Comment: @PetahChristian Thanks. I sent a log to Apple and modified log image to text. If you want to test it, just make a project with enabling notification interface. And, set the option "Wants Sash Blur" static notification interface. before running, you have to add a activate code to enable to connect with watch simulator into an Appdelegate.

Comment: if WCSession.isSupported(){
         let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
         session.activateSession()
}