# apple watch notification scene is not opening in simulator in xcode 7.0

Tags: ios9, xcode7, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am working on apple watch app..Main Watch App & glance scene are loading perfectly in simulator but when i try to open Notification scene, simulator is getting crashed with error Carousel quit unexpectedly..I am not able to fix this issue..following is crash report i get..thanks in advance

```
Process:               Carousel [3570]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/Carousel.app/Carousel
Identifier:            Carousel
Version:               5.3 (5.3)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [3562]
Responsible:           launchd_sim [3562]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-01-04 15:03:13.290 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        913FDA8E-9570-236E-EC4D-0CB9C56246DE


Time Awake Since Boot: 18000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[3570]: autorelease pool page 0x7a523000 corrupted
  magic     0xff9999ff 0xff9999ff 0xff9999ff 0xff9999ff
  should be 0xa1a1a1a1 0x4f545541 0x454c4552 0x21455341
  pthread   0xff9999ff
  should be 0x75751d4

CoreSimulator 179 - Device: Apple Watch - 38mm - Runtime: watchOS 2.0 (13S343) - DeviceType: Apple Watch - 38mm

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0606c956 _objc_trap() + 0
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0606c9dd _objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 99
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x06081610 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::busted(bool) + 152
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0607fb15 objc_object::rootAutorelease2() + 49
4   com.apple.PepperUICore          0x04236d1a _PUICBlurApply + 656
5   com.apple.PepperUICore          0x042372bf PUICBlurApply + 24
6   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x0392c74f -[CUISAlertPlatterView updateBlurWithContext:] + 885
7   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x0392c3ca -[CUISAlertPlatterView updateBlurIfNeeded] + 129
8   com.apple.CarouselUIServices    0x0392c1bd -[CUISAlertPlatterView didMoveToWindow] + 68
9   com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b78a20 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 2053
10  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b785f5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
11  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b785f5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
12  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b785f5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
13  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b8f6fe -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 85
14  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b785f5 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 986
15  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b6c3d0 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 180
16  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b6c2a8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 489
17  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b7b9d6 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2307
18  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04b6a2a7 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
19  com.apple.Carousel              0x000b1299 0x43000 + 451225
20  com.apple.Carousel              0x00137de0 0x43000 + 1002976
21  com.apple.Carousel              0x001dc147 0x43000 + 1675591
22  com.apple.Carousel              0x001714b4 0x43000 + 1238196
23  com.apple.Carousel              0x0019c05b 0x43000 + 1413211
24  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023349a0 __22-[BSTransaction begin]_block_invoke + 115
25  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023393a3 -[BSTransaction _preventTransactionCompletionForReason:ignoringAuditHistory:andExecuteBlock:] + 64
26  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x023348c7 -[BSTransaction begin] + 873
27  com.apple.Carousel              0x000b0451 0x43000 + 447569
28  com.apple.Carousel              0x000af959 0x43000 + 444761
29  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x02345df1 -[BSEventQueueEvent _execute] + 43
30  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x02345dc1 -[BSEventQueueEvent executeFromEventQueue] + 33
31  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x0233dc29 -[BSEventQueue _processNextEvent] + 354
32  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x0233d0d2 -[BSEventQueue _executeOrPendEvents:position:] + 954
33  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x0233d183 -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvents:atPosition:] + 48
34  com.apple.BaseBoard             0x0233d14b -[BSEventQueue executeOrInsertEvent:atPosition:] + 92
35  com.apple.Carousel              0x000aefaf 0x43000 + 442287
36  com.apple.Carousel              0x00091ac4 0x43000 + 322244
37  com.apple.Carousel              0x000919c2 0x43000 + 321986
38  com.apple.Carousel              0x0017cb14 0x43000 + 1284884
39  com.apple.Carousel              0x0017c93a 0x43000 + 1284410
40  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04ac7c4b _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 337
41  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04adc7a9 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 103
42  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04aea24e _afterCACommitHandler + 102
43  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x06579c8e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
44  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x06579bee __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
45  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656f56c __CFRunLoopRun + 1340
46  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656ed76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
47  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656eb8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
48  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x04a73097 GSEventRunModal + 192
49  com.apple.GraphicsServices      0x04a72ed4 GSEventRun + 104
50  com.apple.UIKit                 0x04abb4a1 UIApplicationMain + 160
51  com.apple.Carousel              0x000fdf3a 0x43000 + 765754
52  libdyld.dylib                   0x07261ae1 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a78ce kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0722b2de _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 257
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0722b02e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 60

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a09ce mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0759fa70 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x06570246 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656f626 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656ed76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656eb8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x04627601 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 308
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x046cd9cd -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
8   com.apple.UIKit                 0x0514bff2 -[UIStatusBarServerThread main] + 967
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x046d9e84 __NSThread__start__ + 1346
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fc25 _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fb9b _pthread_start + 162
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce32 thread_start + 34

Thread 3:: com.apple.springboard.backgroundappservices
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a09ce mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0759fa70 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x06570246 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656f626 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656ed76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656eb8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Carousel              0x000e63ed 0x43000 + 668653
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fc25 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fb9b _pthread_start + 162
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce32 thread_start + 34

Thread 4:: com.apple.springboard.icongeneration
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a09ce mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0759fa70 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x06570246 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 214
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656f626 __CFRunLoopRun + 1526
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656ed76 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x0656eb8b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   com.apple.Carousel              0x000e64e3 0x43000 + 668899
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fc25 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756fb9b _pthread_start + 162
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce32 thread_start + 34

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.opengl.cvmDoWork
0   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09662a93 llvm::PHINode::removeIncomingValue(unsigned int, bool) + 99
1   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x0934a0e4 llvm::CloneAndPruneFunctionInto(llvm::Function*, llvm::Function const*, llvm::ValueMap<llvm::Value const*, llvm::WeakVH, llvm::ValueMapConfig<llvm::Value const*, llvm::sys::SmartMutex<false> > >&, bool, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<llvm::ReturnInst*>&, char const*, llvm::ClonedCodeInfo*, llvm::DataLayout const*, llvm::Instruction*) + 3844
2   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09351b20 llvm::InlineFunction(llvm::CallSite, llvm::InlineFunctionInfo&, bool) + 3568
3   libLLVMContainer.dylib          0x09350d1b llvm::InlineFunction(llvm::CallInst*, llvm::InlineFunctionInfo&, bool) + 43
4   libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18d0c33a cvmAddOperationWithInlines + 2458
5   libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18d0c4f4 cvmAddOperationWithInline + 94
6   libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18d497ce glvmBuildFPTransformFunction + 19182
7   libGLVMPlugin.dylib             0x18d0aa52 cvmsPluginElementBuild + 1378
8   libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x08c07110 cvmsCompBuildElement + 121
9   libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x08c0bf5f cvmsServerElementBuild + 1002
10  libCoreVMClient.dylib           0x08c07a37 cvms_element_build_from_source + 107
11  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib      0x08bff872 cvm_deferred_build_modular(void*) + 393
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0723c40d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x07224102 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1065
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x07223a4d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 563
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0722727e _dispatch_queue_override_invoke_owning + 32
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0723c40d _dispatch_client_callout + 14
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x07225624 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 744
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x07225335 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f653 _pthread_wqthread + 724
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x075a6e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756f72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0756ce0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 11:

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0xff9999ff  ecx: 0xbffba860  edx: 0x00002060
  edi: 0x0608158b  esi: 0x0606c986  ebp: 0xbffba8f8  esp: 0xbffba8cc
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010282  eip: 0x0606c956   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x7ace4400

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34523803/4151918

Comment: nice link..after unchecking wants sash blur notification simulator loads perfectly..but I was not able to figure out solution discussed in the link & does it affect real device notifications ?